# Fill empty C string correctly

Tags: c, string, encryption

I am trying to implement the "hebrew encryption", which works as follows:

- Enter number of columns and rows
- Enter text to encrypt
- Fill array with text
- Output text collumns first

Example:

- 5 by 4: "This is an example.."

> ```
> This
> is an
> exam
> ple..
> ```

- Output: "Ti phseli xesaa. nm."

However, i have trouble with text that is shorter than the array has space:

- 5 by 4: "This is an"

> ```
> This 
> is an
>
>  ????
> ```

Where '?' are random(?) characters.

My guess is, that I do not format the string correctly. Currently I check wether a character is '\n' or '\0' and replace it with a whitespace.

Any help is appreciated.

My code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    int x, y; 

    printf("Please input rows and collumns: \n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    scanf("%d", &y);
    char string[x*y];

    printf("Please insert text: \n");
    fgets(string, x*y, stdin);              //ignore \n from previous scanf (otherwise terminates
    fgets(string, x*y, stdin);              //immediatly as \n is still there)

    int k = 0;
    char code[y][x];
    for(int i=0; i < x*y; i++){
        if(string[i] == '\n' || string[i] == '\0')
            string[i] = ' ';
    }
    for(int i=0; i < y; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < x; j++){
            code[i][j] = string[k];
            k++;
        }
    } 

    //output of matrix
    for(int i=0; i < y; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < x; j++){
            printf("%c ",code[i][j]); 
        }
        printf("\n");
    } 

    //matrix to message
    k = 0;
    char message[128];
    for(int j=0; j < x; j++){
        for(int i=0; i < y; i++){
            message[k] = code[i][j];
            k++;
        }
    } 

    printf("%s \n", message);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: string size and fgets argument should be `x*y+1`, else you'll miss the last charaacter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nul pad the string
then wen reading out the result skip the nuls

`char string[x*y+1]; // you had it too small`

...

```
    fgets(string, x*y+1, stdin);              //immediatly as \n is still there)
    int num_read = strlen(string);
    if(num_read < x*y+1 )
       memset(string+num_read,'\0',x*y+1-num_read);
    if (string[num_read ] == '\n' )
        string[num_read ] = '\0';
```

...

```
    char message[x*y+1];  // was way too small!
    for(int j=0; j < x; j++){
        for(int i=0; i < y; i++){
            if(code[i][j])
              message[k] = code[i][j];
            k++;
        }
    } 
    message[k]='\0'
```

Comment: Could you please explain why message[x*y] is too small? Why is it exactly +11? My code gives me the output with a text that fills the the array completely, so I wonder why the string should be bigger for smaller inputs.

Comment: @kernelpanic it's too small because you need a slot for `'\0'` on the end if all the x*y spaces are filled, `+11` was  a typo, should be `+1`

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems

1. You need to initialize all the bytes in the `string` variable, instead of doing with the `for` loop, you can add this before the `fgets`

   ```
   memset(string, ' ', x * y);
   ```

   so now all bytes in the string are spaces then you can remove the trailing `'\n'` and change the terminating `'\0'` with a space, after the `fgets` with

   ```
   size_t length;

   length = strlen(string);
   if (string[length - 1] == '\n')
       string[length - 1] = ' ';
   string[length] = ' ';
   ```
2. You need to add a terminating `'\0'` to the `message` variable, in the loop where you fill `message` you append `message[k] = '\0';` after the loop terminates

   ```
   k = 0;
   char message[128];
   for(int j=0; j < x; j++){
       for(int i=0; i < y; i++){
           message[k] = code[i][j];
           k++;
       }
   }
   message[k] = '\0';
   ```